# Proguard c retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, proguard

Делаю обфускацию своего кода нашел интересное решение добавление keep правила

```
-keepattributes !*Annotation*
```

Это убирает метоинформацию, и делает код, как по мне, менее читабельным но заметил что удаляются аннотации с retrofit interface и выглядит так

```
public interface SiApi {
    Object b(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

    Object e(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

    Object c(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

    Object a(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

    Object d(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

    Object a(RequestBody var1, RequestBody var2, Part var3, Continuation<? super Unit> var4);

    Object a(int var1, Continuation<? super NextAction> var2);
}
```

а хотелось бы такой вид

```
public interface SiApi {
   @GET("***")
    Object b(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

@GET("***")
    Object e(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

@GET("***")
    Object c(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

@GET("***")
    Object a(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

@GET("***")
    Object d(String var1, Continuation<? super FirstAction> var2);

 @Multipart
    @POST("***")
    Object a(RequestBody var1, RequestBody var2, Part var3, Continuation<? super Unit> var4);

@GET("***")
    Object a(int var1, Continuation<? super NextAction> var2);
}
```

Как сохранить аннотации для отдельных классов?

Comment: Зачем вам это? Читается хуже и отлично. Обфускация и сделана против взлома

Comment: Падает с ошибкой при запуске, что не находит эти аннотации

Comment: Попробуйте убрать !

Comment: Тогда вернеться метаинформации, пока так и было решено оставить, так как е знаю как их сохранить

Comment: с чего она вернется? У меня без ! прописано

Comment: Хотя и с ! работает, проверил

Comment: Метаинформация есть в каждом обфусцированном классе, в аннотации @MetaInfo, в которой содержаться имена некоторых обфусцированных методов, переменных, что как по мне портит смысл обфускации

Answer (score 0):

Proguard удаляет аннотации и меняет название переменных из-за этого Retrofit не понимает как правильно создать объект.

Добавь правило для Proguard, чтобы он не трогал классы

```
-keep class package.to.yourmodels.** { *; }
```